# How can I bind text and have it format itself on the UI?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, format, dependency-properties

How can I bind text and have it format itself on the UI?

For example, suppose the string in the ViewModel is this:

```
myDependencyProperty = @"<b>Title: </b>My title\n<b>Description: </b>This is my description.\n";
```

and in the View layer I have this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding myDependencyProperty}" />
```

The problem is that it gets displayed as is. But I want it to be formatted accordingly, as follows:

> **Title:** My Window
>
> **Description:** This is my description.

How can I get that done?

Thank you.

Comment: I won't make this as a link only answer (which SE usually frowns upon) - the code is to big to post here. WPF doesn't support HTML codes like this as standard. However, I did create an enhanced TextBlock control that will handle your requirements - see my blog post http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-controls-formatted-textblock/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextBlock does not support formatting, use instead a RichtextBox combined with flow doc.
also WPF is not HTML so  will not cause line break or  for bold.

```
        public FlowDirection rtbFlowDoc { get; set; }

        var para = new Paragraph();

        para.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run(sText + "\n")));

        rtbFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(para);
```

in your xaml bind the richtextbox to the flow doc

```
Document="{Binding MainModel.RtbFlowDoc}"
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.